# Как на Java скрыть кнопки в правом верхнем углу окна?

Tags: java

Всем доброго времени суток! Необходимо скрыть кнопки: закрыть, развернуть на весь экран, свернуть. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

у объекта окна метод setUndecorated(true).

**Добавлено.**

```
public class NewClass extends JWindow{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        NewClass nc = new NewClass();
        nc.setSize(100, 200);
        nc.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: пробовал, даже import javax.swing.*; вставил. 

Visual Studio 2005 (программу желательно сделать именно на нем)  выдает ошибку 
Cannot find method 'setUndecorated(boolean)' in
'WindowsApplication4.watchwindow'

Comment: Обновлен ответ.

Comment: Cannot find type 'JWindow' :(

Comment: JWindow по-моему JFrame, раз уж на то пошло.

Comment: На кой чёрт вам VS2005 дался? Он же только на J# вроде..

Answer (score 1):

Оо... А как это Вы так в Java ставите `nc.setVisible(true);` если дожно быть так:

```
JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
jFrame.setResizable(false);
```

Да и true - это правда, соответственно, должно стоять false для того, чтобы скрыть, а если используете `JWindows.setResizable(false)` - пропадает еще и название title, соответственно, JFrame лучше в этом случае.